# Why should $ s \in ( 0 , 1 ) $ for splinter to be approximately geometric?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Recently I was studying functional equation, in which I came across the following paragraphs in Christopher G. Small's book [Functional Equations and How to Solve Them](https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Functional%20Equations%20and%20How%20To%20Solve%20Them%20-%20Christopher%20G.%20Small.pdf).

> **3.5.1 The Koenigs algorithm for Schröder's equation**
>
> First note that if $ f ( x ) $ is any solution to Schröder's equation
> $$ f [ \alpha ( x ) ] = s f ( x ) $$
> then so is any constant multiple of $ f ( x ) $.
>
> If the splinter of $ \alpha $ behaves approximately as a geometric sequence, a solution can be found. The splinter $ \alpha ^ n ( x ) $ is said to be *approximately geometric* if there exists a number $ s \in ( 0 , 1 ) $ such that
> $$ \lim _ { n \to \infty } \frac { \alpha ^ n ( x ) } { s ^ n } $$
> exists, is finite, and is nonzero. In this case we say that the splinter has rate $ s $.
>
> On a domain of values $ x $ where the splinter of $ x $ is approximately geometric with rate $ s $ independent of $ x $, a solution to Schröder's equation is given by
> $$ f ( x ) = \lim _ { n \to \infty } \frac { \alpha ^ n ( x ) } { s ^ n } $$

Why should $ s \in ( 0 , 1 ) $?

---

*Small, Christopher G.*, Functional equations and how to solve them, Problem Books in Mathematics. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-0-387-34539-0/pbk). xii, 129 p. (2007). [ZBL1152.39300](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1152.39300).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: It seems that the condition $ s \in ( 0 , 1 ) $ is not necessary for the part of the text you've shared in your post; for **any** $ s $ and any $ \alpha $ with approximately geometric splinter with rate $ s $, the function $ f $ given by the limit satisfies Schröder's equation with parameter $ s $. I suppose the condition $ s \in ( 0 , 1 ) $ is related to some other part of the text that you haven't shred here. To find out what it is for, it might be better that you give reference to the source, and check the other parts.

Comment: @CHEMOJEE You're welcome. I edited the post so that you become more familiar with the standards the community expects, and follow the pattern in your future posts. Sharing images is discouraged, unless really necessary. For example, the text in the image doesn't appear in search.

Comment: @MohsenShahriari Ok, It is actually from the book "Functional Equations and how to solve them" by Christopher G small (chapter 3)

Comment: @MohsenShahriari It is available in this link(https://www.isinj.com/mt-usamo/Functional%20Equations%20and%20How%20To%20Solve%20Them%20-%20Christopher%20G.%20Small.pdf)

Comment: @CHEMOJEE I added your reference, the link and a citation at the end of the post. Again, I hope this helps you for your future activity on the site. Always include the source of the problem, your attempts, and all relevant content in the post. Take a look at [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/229831). Maybe [How to ask a homework question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/229831) will also be useful. I hope you have fun, learn a lot, and help others learn on MSE.

Comment: It strikes me as a bit odd that the author being quoted seems to be using the variable $s$ in two different ways, first as a (fixed?) parameter in the equation $f[\alpha(x)]=sf(x)$, and then as a number determined in the definition of "approximately geometric." Is there supposed to be some connection between the two uses?

Comment: @BarryCipra I think the author just restricts the value of parameter 's' in the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition $ s \in ( 0 , 1 ) $ is not necessary for the part you've quoted; in fact it works for any nonzero value of $ s $.

This condition is set only for convenience, as is first put forward in the second paragraph of Section 3.4 of the book. The idea is that

1. the case $ s = 0 $ has a trivial set of solutions: those functions that are identically zero on the range of $ \alpha $, and with arbitrary values at other points of the domain of interest;
2. the case $ s = 1 $ can be treated separately, as is done in Section 3.3 of the book;
3. the case $ s > 1 $ can be reduced to the case $ 0 < s < 1 $ if $ \alpha $ is invertible: $ f \left( \alpha ^ { - 1 } ( x ) \right) = \frac 1 s f ( x ) $ is another instance of Schröder's equation;
4. the case $ s < 0 $ can be solved more easily using the solution of the case $ s > 0 $: $ f \left( \alpha ^ 2 ( x ) \right) = s ^ 2 f ( x ) $ is another instance of Schröder's equation, and one can search for the solutions of the original equation among the solutions obtained from the other one.

So, as is mentioned in the second paragraph of Section 3.4 of the book, it often happens that one can transform the original problem to a case where $ s \in ( 0 , 1 ) $, and hence focusing on this case is not much restrictive.